# Clearing text input in React when changing focus to another textbox

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Let's say I have Textbox A and B. I click textbox A so the focus is on it, then I type in "hello" on A. Then without clearing the text input in A, I click on textbox B. When doing so, since textbox A lost the focus, I want the text input cleared as soon as I hit textbox B. Is there a react component that fits this description?

Answer (score 1):

clear the value of textbox A `onBlur`

```js
//this is textbox A
<input
  type='text'
  onBlur={(e) => e.target.value = ''}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the onBlur event on text box A and clear your textBox A state value.